# How can I extract onError method of rxjava by using lambda

Tags: android, lambda, rx-java

I have a network requst:

```
userApi.getUserInfoByUid (AuthUtils.getUid (ctx), AuthUtils.getToken (ctx))
            .doOnNext (u -> saveToCache (u))
            .observeOn (AndroidSchedulers.mainThread ())
            .subscribe (u -> {
                if (updateListener != null)
                    updateListener.onUpdate (u);
            },e->{
                Toast.makeText (ctx,"network error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            });
```

you know,many request maybe has network error, so i extract OnError() Method. such as:

```
 abstract class Mysubscrib<T> extends Subscriber<T>{

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText (ctx,"network error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
}

    userApi.getUserInfoByUid (AuthUtils.getUid (ctx), AuthUtils.getToken (ctx))
            .doOnNext (u -> saveToCache (u))
            .observeOn (AndroidSchedulers.mainThread ())
            .subscribe (new Mysubscrib<UserInfo> () {
                @Override
                public void onNext(UserInfo userInfo) {
                    if (updateListener != null)
                        updateListener.onUpdate (userInfo);
                }
            });
```

but if i do that,i can not use lambda,it's feel bad.how can i use:

```
userApi.getUserInfoByUid (AuthUtils.getUid (ctx), AuthUtils.getToken (ctx))
            .doOnNext (u -> saveToCache (u))
            .observeOn (AndroidSchedulers.mainThread ())
            .subscribe (u->{
                if (updateListener != null)
                    updateListener.onUpdate (u);
            });
```

Comment: You can see [this example in GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/HelloRxJavaRetrolambda) and [this blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/rxjava-retrolambda/#sthash.z5AT4BS4.dpbs) Happy code!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, java and its lambda expressions don't allow to do such kind of things. The easiest way to workaround it is to provide an additional factory method for `Mysubscrib` that accepts `Action1` as an argument:

```
abstract class Mysubscrib<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
    public static <T> Mysubscrib<T> create(final Action1<? super T> action) {
        return new Mysubscrib<T>() {
            @Override
            public onNext(final T value) {
                action.call(value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText (ctx,"network error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
userApi.getUserInfoByUid (AuthUtils.getUid (ctx), AuthUtils.getToken (ctx))
        .doOnNext (u -> saveToCache (u))
        .observeOn (AndroidSchedulers.mainThread ())
        .subscribe (Mysubscrib.create(u -> {
            if (updateListener != null)
                updateListener.onUpdate (u);
        });
```